# Ajaxsubmit not a function, 503 error?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Есть проблема при добавлении комментария через Ajax , сайт зависает с не полученным ответом , в консоли показывает 503 error и указывает ошибку на Jquery , попробовал поставить новую jquery тогда вылезает ошибка ajax not a function и страница перезагружается , странность проблемы в том что на свой пост который добавил именно я , комментарий успешно добавляется без каких либо ошибок , но стоит мне либо любому юзеру сайт замирает с ошибкой 503 
Скрин где именно показывает ошибку в jquery.js
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

AJAX отправки комментария

```
$(function() {

$(document).on('focus', ".comment-editor  textarea", function() {
    $(this).css('height', '50px').data('height', '50px');
    var target = $($(this).data('target'));
    target.find('.comment-editor-footer').fadeIn();
});

$(document).on('submit', ".comment-editor", function() {
    var text = $(this).find('textarea');
    var imageInput = $(this).find('input[type=file]');
    var form = $(this);
    if (text.val() == '' && imageInput.val() == '') {
        show_comment_add_error(form, 'default');
        return false
    };
    var commentList = $(".comment-lists-" + $(this).data('type') + '-' +$(this).data('type-id'));
    toogleCommentIndicator(form);

    $(this).ajaxSubmit({
        url : baseUrl + 'comment/add',
        type : 'POST',
        dataType : 'json',
        success : function(data) {
            var json = data;
            if (json.status == 0) {
                show_comment_add_error(form,json.message);
            } else {
                div = $("<div style='display: none'></div>");
                div.html(json.comment);
                //commentList.append(div);
                $(".comment-lists-" + form.data('type') + '-' + form.data('type-id')).each(function() {
                    $(this).append(json.comment);
                    //alert(".comment-lists-" + form.data('type') + '-' + form.data('type-id'))
                });
                $(".comment-count-"+form.data('type') + '-' + form.data('type-id')).each(function() {
                    $(this).html(json.count);
                })
                notifySuccess(json.message);

                resent_comment_form(form);
                reloadInits();
            }

            toogleCommentIndicator(form);
        },
        error : function() {
            toogleCommentIndicator(form);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery тут ни при чем, [503 - это ошибка сервера](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_HTTP#503).
Для того, чтобы её починить, вам надо дебажить серверную сторону,
а на клиентской стороне вам нужно только правильно обработать её в `error` коллбеке